# sharepint type script build error

Tags: angular, sharepoint

I am working in SPFX with angular 2. I wanted to use sharepoint type script in my project. I have installed the sharepoint type script with npm command `typings install dt~sharepoint --global --save`.

When I tried to build the project with gulp serve command it give me 43 error all are in sharepoint dt. The error is `Error - typescript - typings\globals\sharepoint\index.d.ts(11190,40): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Sys'.`

It seems some depency is not installed but I could not able to figure out which one. Please share your knowledge with me to fix this problem.